# Need guidance on implementing a Primary Flight Display

Tags: java, objective-c, opengl, graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm a developer familiar with Ada, C, Obj.C (iOS), and C#. I would like to create an application to show some data about a robot I'm building. However I have never done graphics  with either Mac libraries or OpenGL before.

What I'm trying to achieve is shown in the image below. I have tested Processing to create some stuff. But it's too complicated and Processing is far from powerful for this kind of application. It can't even rotate a line around its center without writing some nasty code.

**Requirements**:
Graphing capabilities (e.g. voltage drawn in respect to time), Google maps API, gradients, 2D animations, masks.

**Questions**:

1. What should I learn? Is this possible to implement using only the Mac libraries/frameworks or should I use OpenGL?
2. Is it best to do it using Obj c? Or is java worth the learning? How good is Java with graphics like this? This thing is that if I program this using Obj C then its not cross platform.
3. Any other tips you can give?

Later on, I´d like to add a google maps to show the position of the plane. All data is transmitted through Wifi. 10Hz.

[image]

Comment: `Requirements: Graphing capabilities (e.g. voltage drawn in respect to time), Google maps API, gradients, 2D animations, masks.` - Where will this run? WPF is the best UI framework in the history of mankind, and has built-in support for all these things you mentioned, but it only runs in Windows =( (XP or later)

Comment: As HighCore mentioned, is it a display for embedded hardware, desktop gui, or web gui?

Comment: Desktop and later on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thread of someone doing this with opengl and js: http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php?topic=3076.0

1. Yes you can do this in opengl, but you may consider Cairo which is 2d rendering and may be simpler. It certainly depends on if you need 3d rendering or not. In case of 3d rendering OpenGL may be a better bet, then trying to fit it into the Cairo system.
2. If you want it to be cross platform, I'd personally do it in Java or Python, but there are opengl and cairo bindings for most languages. If java I recommend trying LWJGL.
3. You'll also need to consider what UI framework to use, since you may need buttons and all that jazz. I personally like Qt, but WPF is also quite good.

See here for Cairo Docs: http://cairographics.org/documentation/

In addition this question came up here and there are more suggestions in the comment threads: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/479476-how-would-you-program-a-pfd-primary-flight-display/

I'm not sure how great animation with cairo is, but here is a tutorial demonstrating that: http://cairographics.org/threaded_animation_with_cairo/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, Im waiting for more options to compare with.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that some specific library will accomplish all the requirements. Probably you will need to use a mix of them.

If you ask me, Id go for a combination of web ui frameworks. Based on the image you have shared, im sure that most of that graphical components can be constructed using ExtJs framework (see these examples: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/, http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/extjs-build/examples/charts/Gauge.html, http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/extjs-build/examples/sandbox/sandbox.html).
For the central panel, maybe there is no library that provides a generic widget like that, and so I would go for a custom HTML5 Canvas implementation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element).

Just want to add that I woudl go for the web way simply because:

- Community is BIG for almost any library
- Cross platform issues would not be a problem
- Most of Web UI frameworks are mature, and have out of the box widgets ready to be used.
- Communicating with external APIs (like Google Maps as you mentioned) is a piece of cake using web.

Comment: Unfortunaltey the web method will be a problem because of lack of support for a fast and reliable serial port communication. As far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

Ah, this is personal experience I've had while I built my final year engineering project(which was incidentally a robot that could fly) - And I've built something like this before.

I used Java for graphing and telemetry data tool with flight display system like that(and it was sufficient).

But if you are good with a programming language, then you can do it in any language of your choice. Yes, Mac + OpenGL + ObjC is good combination too. My aim was to keep the code as portable as possible.